# HTML required tag not validating form

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the following form with required tags does not actaully validate my input, and always alerts "ok", what am I missing?

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="inputFirstName">Förnamn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Förnamn" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="inputLastName">Efternamn</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Efternamn" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="inputPhone">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Telefon"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="inputMobile">Mobiltelefon</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMobile" placeholder="Mobiltelefon"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label for="inputCompany">Företag</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCompany" placeholder="Företag" required/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 pull-right" data-bind="click: submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript, where i want to alert "ok" if validation passes:

```
vm.submit = function(){
            alert("ok");
        };
```

Comment: You must have something else in play because your code exactly like it sits works fine in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5u1zdtqy/

Comment: @maxshuty hmm, wonder if bootstrap is interfering somehow.

Comment: turns out knockout overrides it...

Comment: heh that'll do it